# GAE Development datastore not there

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, gae-eclipse-plugin

Indigo on Windows 7 Pro 64bit

Just bringing up an app for the first time; my datastore code is a close copy of various examples out there, and is just trying to save a single simple object.

The pm.MakePersistent(o) apparently succeeds (i.e. doesn't throw an exception), but the datastore viewer shows no objects, and the local_db.bin file does not appear (although datastore-indexes-auto.xml was generated in that directory).

A subsequent query for the object (using a known field value) returns nothing (unsurprising given the viewer shows nothing.)

I suspect a workspace configuration problem, but would have thought some sort of error would have appeared...

Comment: Can't self-answer yet... Found it: I left off (identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION) from the @PersistenceCapable declaration for my class.

And no warnings or errors.

Still, reading for comprehension fail, Paul.